# Pandas style-dataframe has multi-index columns misaligned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, alignment, pandas-styles

I need to style a Pandas dataframe that has a multi-index column arrangement.  As an example of my dataframe, consider:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True for a in range(12)]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a,b,c) for a in ['Tim','Sarah'] for b in ['house','car','boat'] for c in ['new','used']])
df
```

This displays the multi-index columns just as I would expect it to, and is easy to read:
[image]

However, when I convert it to a style dataframe:

```
df.style
```

The column headers suddenly shift and it becomes confusing to figure out where each level begins and ends:

[image]

How can I undo this, to return it to the more readable left-justified setup? I looked through about 10 other posts on SO but none addressed this issue.

### Update

My primary product is a .to_excel() output, and it displays correctly, I just learned. However this issue is still open for solutions.

Comment: It doesn't for me with you df. Works just fine.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes thank you, but I don't know what to do with that! I'm on python 3.8.3, and this was in a Jupyter Notebook. You?

Comment: Same version of python, pandas 1.05 and in a notebook as well.